# Time complexity of a 2-heap question

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, heaps

The problem statement is pretty straightforward: given an array of integers and a window size, return an array of doubles of the median of each window.

$arr = 1, 3, 5, 10, 6, 9, 2$ and $k = 3$ would yield a result of $3, 5, 6, 9, 6$.

Using [std::priority_queue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) (in C++) for the heap implementation, there's a **minHeap** and **maxHeap**. In a single iteration, insert the value entering our window in the correct heap, rebalance as necessary, add the median to the result (if the window is big enough), then remove the value which is leaving the window from whatever heap it's in: This could require moving all but 1 heap element to the other heap, then moving them back.

The lesson I saw this on actually inherits from priority queue and implements remove functionality: Linear search [O(k)], then removes the item [O(log k)].  It claims O(n * k) complexity as at each iteration the insertion is O(log k) and the search to remove is O(k). I assume in an interview extending a heap beyond it's traditional form is not only unnecessary but probably frowned upon.

I'm curious of the complexity at which the version w/o the direct removal would run.  The O(n) part is obvious but the sub operations not as clear to me.  A heap will generally have k/2 items in it.  In the worst case you delete [O(log k)] and then insert [O(1)] each one.  My mind is telling me O(n * k log k) but I wouldn't bet my house on it.

For the record: Not looking for an optimal solution - just the runtime of this one.

**Insertion Algorithm:**
We accept an integer `n` as input.

1. If `n` is smaller than the top element of `maxHeap`, push it on `maxHeap` and go to step 3.
2. Push `n` on `minHeap`.
3. If `maxHeap`'s size is 2 or more than `minHeap`'s size, move the top element of `maxHeap` to `minHeap` and go to step 5.
4. If `minHeap`'s size exceeds `maxHeap`'s size, move the top element of `minHeap` to `maxHeap`.
5. Stop the algorithm.

**Obtaining The Median:**

1. If sizes of `minHeap` and `maxHeap` are the same, then return the arithmetic mean of their top elements and go to step 4.
2. If `maxHeap`'s size exceeds `minHeap`'s size, return the top element of `maxHeap` and go to step 4.
3. If `minHeap`'s size exceeds `maxHeap`, return the top element of `minHeap`.
4. Stop the algorithm.

**Removal Algorithm:**
We accept an integer `n` as input.

1. If `num` is not greater than the top element of `maxHeap`, remove the current top element from `maxHeap` and insert it to `minHeap`, until `n` becomes the new top element of `maxHeap`. Else skip to step 4.
2. Remove the top element of `maxHeap`.
3. Remove the current top element of `minHeap` and insert it to `maxHeap`, until the sizes of `minHeap` and `maxHeap` will differ by no more than 1. Go to step 7.
4. Remove the current top element from `minHeap` and insert it to `maxHeap`, until `n` becomes the new top element of `minHeap`.
5. Remove the top element of `minHeap`.
6. Remove the current top element of `maxHeap` and insert it to `minHeap`, until the sizes of `minHeap` and `maxHeap` will differ by no more than 1.
7. Stop the algorithm.

**Finding Sliding Window Median:**
We accept an array of integers `arr`, and an integer `k` as input.

1. Set `left` to $0$. Set `right` to $0$. Set `result` to $0$.
2. Insert (by using **Insertion Algorithm** above) the element of `arr` with index `right`.
3. If `k-1` is not greater than `right`, add median (found by **Obtaining The Median** algorithm above) to `result`. Else go to step 6.
4. Remove the element of `arr` with index `left`.
5. Add $1$ to `left`.
6. If `right` is less than the greatest index of `arr`, add $1$ to `right` and go to step 2.
7. Return the current value of `result` and stop the algorithm.

This last algorithm is where the mystery is. Worst case we have is to remove a number at the bottom of a $k/2$ sized heap. Would that be $\log k$ for $k/2$ operations then $O(1)$ for $k/2-1$ operations?

Comment: I'm confused by the question.  Can you replace the "Using.." and "The lesson.." paragraphs with a clear description of the algorithm you want to know the runtime of?  I suggest using concise pseudocode.  Right now it reads like "here's one algorithm, but wait, that's not what I want to know about, I want to know the runtime of some variant" - and I don't understand exactly what either the first algorithm or the variant is.  No need to describe other versions that you don't want analyzed; it suffices to describe the one algorithm you do want to analyze.

Comment: Can you please sketch `the version w/o the direct removal` explicitly? I don't "see" it.

Comment: (I do "see" use of a self-balancing order-statistics tree.)

Comment: I've updated the post w/ the entire code (which is kind of wordy).  90% of it is keeping track of the heaps.  I forgot if you're not brushing up on interview skills this stuff can get a bit abstract.

Comment: Sorry, but we discourage code on this site.  Please replace the code with concise pseudocode.  Many people here might not read C++ code; and code tends to be a lot more verbose than necessary to present the algorithm.

Comment: Sorry -- was not aware.  Not done psuedocode in a while so hopefully it doesn't suck too badly. :)  Thanks for your patience thus far. :D

Comment: In your pseudo code, I see *direct removal*. Just *what is* `the version w/o the direct removal`?

Comment: It uses a data structure that extends the heap.  In the remove function, it figures out which heap the item is in, does a linear scan of the heap, then removes it from whatever position it's in.

Comment: (There are at least two interpretations to *direct removal*: a) direct support of removal of an item with a specified value (position in order or implementation would be possible, too) b) removal at the time the item transits from *shall be accounted for* to *shall be ignored* - the latter was what I was thinking of claiming to see *direct removal*.)

Comment: This is one funny application of priority queues/heaps, considering $O(kn)$ looks trivial to achieve keeping $k$ items iterable in order.

Answer (score 0):

Store the window in a self-balancing binary search tree, augmented in the standard way for computing item ranks (each node is augmented with the number of values stored in the subtree rooted at that node).

Each time a value arrives, add it to the tree, remove the one leaving the window, compute the median, and output it.  Each of those operations can be done in $O(\log k)$ time.  (For instance, insert and delete take $O(\log k)$ time, because it is a self-balancing binary tree; finding the median of the values in the tree can be done in $O(\log k)$ time using the augmented rank information.)  Therefore, the total running time to process $n$ items will be $O(n \log k)$.

Comment: Thanks.  I failed to mention that this module was about hitting things w/ a 2-heap approach, so was more curious about the run time of that.

Comment: @kiss-o-matic, that doesn't appear in your problem statement, so I suggest you edit your question to state that clearly and credit the original source or context where you encountered this task.

Answer (score 0):

It’s easier to figure out if k is large, say k = 100.

You start by creating two heaps with 50 elements each, one with the 50 smallest of the first 100 numbers with fast access to the largest one, and one with the 50 largest, with fast access to the smallest one. The median of all 100 items can be found in O(1).

Now you move the window by one position. Element #0 is removed from its heap, element #100 is added to its heap. Then if you are lucky you have two heaps of size 50, if you are unlucky you have one heap of size 49 and one of size 51, and move either the largest of the small numbers, or the smallest of the large numbers, from its heap to the other heap.

For odd k both heaps need a size that is different by one and the heap with the largest number of elements contains the median. For example k=99, your two heaps must contain 49 and 50 elements. If you are unlucky moving the window results in 48 and 51 items and you move one item over.

Since accessing the second element is also quite fast, you can allow a slightly larger size difference of the heaps which may save some insertions.

And you need O(n log k) operations.

PS. Figured out that you can’t delete an arbitrary item from a heap. So you need to keep track of where your k elements in the window are in the heap, but that doesn’t make things much harder. Still O(n log k).